# React - is it ok to store state in a separate file?

Tags: reactjs, state

I'm new to React so apologies for reaching out with what may be a silly or basic question.

Is it a sensible and workable solution to store default state in an external file?

So if I have an app container like this:-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Spy from '../spies/weather/Spy';
import Local from '../local/Local';
import './app.css';
import { state } from './state'

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = state
  }

  onLocationChange = event => {
    this.setState({ location: event.target.value })
    }       
  setWeather() {
    //this.setState( { weather: { weather }});
    console.log(`this is ${this}`);
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Local locationChange={this.onLocationChange}/>
        <Spy location={this.state.location} setWeather={this.setWeather}/>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and a state.js file like this:-

```
export const state = {
    location: '',
    weather: {}
};
```

It apparently works fine, my child component 'Local' has an OnChange event that updates the location property of state clearly visible in the React Dev tools.
Everything I've seen so far has state in the parent container or has used Redux which I might do if I can get my head around React.

I was just after some advice about how to manage scalability in what could become a monster App container with loads of functions but especially a massive state object with some quite obscure defaults.

What would you advise to allow App to grow sensibly - would you partition state in such a way perhaps breaking it down even further? Does it slow things down or create issues?

Thank you!

Phil

Comment: It is valid code and will work, but keeping the state inside the component makes it more readable and can prevent unexpected behaviour. I would only do that if the state would be reused by other components. But be aware that by changing the state in the wrong way, you potentially change the state exported from the separate file. I suggest that you take a look at the React Redux and Immutable libraries for perhaps better solutions for your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React is really flexible when it comes to project structure.
I've see solution like this in the past. If that works well for You than I think it's not a "bad practice" to keep it in a separate file

Take a look here:

https://en.reactjs.org/docs/faq-structure.html

Remember that Redux is something that might help You organize Your state but it's a solution that is not suitable for small projects. When You find Yourself in a situation when You have too much local component state and You pass too much data as props to child components than it should be a yellow alert for You to start thinking about some state manager like Redux :)

Another common approach is to have a "Wrapper component" which will be responsible for keeping and passing down state that is shared across multiple components. Simple state pieces that are only relevant to one particular component can be stored inside this component as a component-level-state.

I hope that answers Your question in some way.

Comment: Yes, thankyou. Helpful - will accept the answer shortly assuming no-one else has much else to add.

Comment: Cool :) I made a small edit. Take a look and have a good day